# Using Android Device Camera through Python

Tags: android, python, camera, usb

How to take pictures through the camera of an android device that is connected to a PC via USB using PYTHON code running on PC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android uses Java for applications, but I am unsure what the APIs are available for the OS.

Offhand I would give this a try: http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/

Comment: Thank you for useful resource. I will try it